# Pandas - Resampling one minute interval of non regularised data in a 3 hour interval and replacing missing data with data in a range of time

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have a non regulirased data in an interval of one minute like this:

```
Date                Vel     Dir
14-11-2001 17:55:00 14.1    35
14-11-2001 17:56:00 10.4    52
14-11-2001 17:57:00 14.8    19
14-11-2001 18:04:00 11.4    54
14-11-2001 18:05:00 7.6     13
```

I want to resample that data for an interval of 3 hours (0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21) in a way that if for example the data at the hour 18 and the minute 00 is missing, i replace it with the closest data in a range of five minutes after or before the 00 minute. In this example i have the time of 17 57 is closer to 18 00 than 18 04 so i replace the data for the missing time 18 00 with the data of 17 57 like this:

```
14-11-2001 15:00:00 5.8     43
14-11-2001 18:00:00 14.8    19
14-11-2001 21:00:00 17.4    68
```

If i don't have data in the interval of five minutes after or before the 00 minute i don't complete the missing data leaving the hour with NaN like this:

```
14-11-2001 15:00:00 5.8     43
14-11-2001 18:00:00 NaN     NaN
14-11-2001 21:00:00 17.4    68
```

I am trying to do this with the .resample('3H') command of pandas but i don't know how to do it replacing the missing values with the closest data in a range of five minutes.

I tried using the np.searchshorted but i was not able to establish the range of five minutes with it so i drop the idea.

My code right now is very simple, i just read a text file with the data and resample it in a 3 hour interval without replacing the data so  my data is looking like this when i extract it for i text file  :

```
Date                Vel     Dir
14-11-2001 15:00:00 5.8     43
14-11-2001 18:00:00     
14-11-2001 21:00:00 17.4    68
```

The code is:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x,'%d %m %Y %H %M')
vento= pd.read_csv('vento.txt',header=0, delim_whitespace= True, parse_dates = [['Dia', 'Mes', 'Ano', 'Hora','Minuto']], index_col = 0, date_parser = dateparse)

vento_2=vento.resample('3H')
vento_2.to_csv(r'data.txt',index=True, index_label=None, sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas-merge-asof) a new pandas 0.19.0 addition.  You will have to test this with more of your input data that you provided here.  But this is one approach.

Be sure your 'Date' field in your original df is datetime data time

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Let's create some three hour blocks of time manually:

```
df_time = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range(start='2001-11-14',end='2001-11-15',freq='3H')})
```

Use `merge_asof` with a tolerance of 5 minutes.

```
df_new = pd.merge_asof(df_time,df, on='Date',tolerance=pd.Timedelta("5 minutes")).fillna('')

print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
                 Date   Vel Dir
0 2001-11-14 00:00:00          
1 2001-11-14 03:00:00          
2 2001-11-14 06:00:00          
3 2001-11-14 09:00:00          
4 2001-11-14 12:00:00          
5 2001-11-14 15:00:00          
6 2001-11-14 18:00:00  14.8  19
7 2001-11-14 21:00:00          
8 2001-11-15 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help and sorry for the delay in replying. Your answer helped me a lot but because of my data i had to make a few changes. In the end, my code is the following (you can see a change the range of interval for 3 minutes instead of 5):

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd


dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x,'%d %m %Y %H %M')

vento = pd.read_csv('vento.txt',header=0, delim_whitespace= True, parse_dates = [['Dia', 'Mes', 'Ano', 'Hora','Minuto']], index_col = False, date_parser = dateparse)
vento1 = vento.rename(columns={'Dia_Mes_Ano_Hora_Minuto': 'Data'})
vento_time = pd.DataFrame({'Data':pd.date_range(start='2016-07-12 18:00:00',end='2017-02-28 21:00:00',freq='3H')})
vento_2 = pd.merge_asof(vento_time,vento1, on='Data',tolerance=pd.Timedelta("3 minutes")).fillna('NAN')
vento_3 = vento_2.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
vento_3.set_index(['Data'], inplace=True)
vento_3.to_csv('vento_3min.csv')
```